# Changing color propery of Listbox on WP7

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7, listbox

I'm beginning with WP7 and I'm trying to change color and other properties of TexBlock. It is included on Listbox and binding to a collection. I am searching for a way like 'OnDataBound'. The value must change depend of the bind object.

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="listBox1"  ItemsSource="{Binding}"  >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Width="418" BorderThickness="1" Margin="2">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"><TextBlock Text="Charater: "/><TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CharacterName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" /></StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"><TextBlock Text="Perk launched: "/><TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CreationDate}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/></StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"><TextBlock Text="Finished at: "/><TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FinishedAt}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/></StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"><TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockStatus" Text="Status: "/><TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Status}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/></StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Depend of Status of binding object, I need change propery of Textblock (color, etc.)
could you please tell me the stating point ?

My binding is this follwing (in .cs):

```
 this.listBox1.DataContext = this.calculatedValues;
```

thanks for your help

Comment: At this time, I'm using a Converter (inherits IValueConverter) and return a SolidColorBrush, that I bind on Forecolor property of a TextBlock. Is it the best way ?

Answer (score 1):

In this example the color if stored in a class called ListItems which is defined as:

```
public class ListItems
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
}
```

An observable colletion of type ListItems is added to the code behind of the MainPage file:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    ObservableCollection<ListItems> items = new ObservableCollection<ListItems>();
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        items.Add(new ListItems() { name = "Item 1", color = "Red" });
        items.Add(new ListItems() { name = "Item 2", color = "Blue" });
        items.Add(new ListItems() { name = "Item 3", color = "Green" });
        items.Add(new ListItems() { name = "Item 4", color = "White" });
        items.Add(new ListItems() { name = "Item 5", color = "Purple" });

        DataContext = this;
        listBox1.ItemsSource = items;
    }
}
```

}

And items of type ListItem are added to the observable collection.

The MainPage.xaml file is then designed to contain a list box that has its ItemTemplate bound to the properties of the ListItem class:

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12" Width="400" Height="400" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Item" Text="{Binding name}" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="40" Foreground="{Binding color}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

The finished page looks like this:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. It is a good solution, but I cannot change the entity binded. But I like this method and will use it as possible.